# Batch or code to copy last file from alphabetical order based on 2 characters?

Tags: batch-file, copy, alphabetical-sort

I need a batch or some code to look up 2 characters in a file name and then copy the file with the latest revision alphabetically.

So for this list of files in a source folder, it would look at the 8th and 9th characters A1, B1 etc and copy ABC0123E1.pdf to destination.

- ABC0123A1.pdf
- ABC0123B1.pdf
- ABC0123C1.pdf
- ABC0123D1.pdf
- ABC0123E1.pdf

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did this help you at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My second answer addresses the focus to the 8th character:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL 
cd test
for /f "tokens=1*" %%x in ('
(for %%a in (*.pdf^) do @(
    set "fname=%%~a"
    ^&call echo %%fname:~7^,1%% %%fname%%^)
^)^|sort /r') do echo %%~y
```

Answer (score 3):

Just modify the options of the `dir` command.
with the option `/on` you get this output:

```
>dir /on /b ABC0123?1.pdf
ABC0123A1.pdf
ABC0123B1.pdf
ABC0123C1.pdf
ABC0123D1.pdf
ABC0123E1.pdf
```

.. and with `/o-n` you get the reverse order:

```
>dir /o-n /b ABC0123?1.pdf
ABC0123E1.pdf
ABC0123D1.pdf
ABC0123C1.pdf
ABC0123B1.pdf
ABC0123A1.pdf
```

For help enter `dir /?` on cmd.

---

And the code is:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /on /b ABC0123?1.pdf') do set "LatestAlfa=%%~a"
echo %LatestAlfa%
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help but i need to focus only on the 8th character in the file name, as the first 3 letters vary.